# Can't locate HTML element on Rotten Tomatoes

Tags: python, selenium, click

I would like to find a movie and get ratings of it on Rotten Tomatoes, but I'm stuck because I don't know how to click on it in search results section. I tried almost every XPATH or CLASS NAME but every time I got error message that it couldn't find the element. I'm using Python Selenium.
My code:

```
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def element(driver, by_x, html_element):
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((by_x, html_element))
        )
        return element
    except:
        print("Can not locate this element")

class rottenTomatoes:
    def __init__(self, film):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./drivers/chromedriver", options=options)
        self.film = film
        self.driver.get("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/")

    def search(self):
        # search for a film
        search_bar = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("search-text")
        search_bar.click()
        search_bar.send_keys(self.film, Keys.RETURN)
        # filter movies only
        element(self.driver, By.XPATH, "//*[@id='main-page-content']/div/section[1]/search-result-          
        container/nav/ul/li[3]/span").click()
        # accept cookies
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("truste-consent-button").click()
        # click on film (THE PROBLEM)
        element(self.driver, By.CLASS_NAME, "media-col thumbnail-group").click()

rottentomatoes = rottenTomatoes("Shawshank")
rottentomatoes.search()
```

EDIT
Error message:

```
Can not locate this element
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "d:\Programovanie\selenium\movie_info\rotten_tomat.py", line 38, in <module>
    rottentomatoes.search()
  File "d:\Programovanie\selenium\movie_info\rotten_tomat.py", line 35, in search  
    element(self.driver, By.CLASS_NAME, "media-col thumbnail-group").click()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Comment: can you include the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


def element(driver, by_x, html_element):
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((by_x, html_element))
        )
        return element
    except:
        print("Can not locate this element")


class rottenTomatoes:
    def __init__(self, film):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            options=options)
        self.film = film
        self.driver.get("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/")

    def search(self):
        # search for a film
        search_bar = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("search-text")
        search_bar.click()
        search_bar.send_keys(self.film, Keys.RETURN)
        # filter movies only
        element(self.driver, By.XPATH, "// *[@id='main-page-content']/div/section[1]/search-result-container/nav/ul/li[3]/span").click()
        # accept cookies
        time.sleep(5)
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_id("truste-consent-button").click()
        except:
            pass

        ele = self.driver.execute_script(
            "return document.querySelector('search-result-container').shadowRoot.querySelector('[type=\"movie\"]').shadowRoot.querySelector('media-row').shadowRoot.querySelector('[class=\"media-row center\"]')")
        # click on film (THE PROBLEM)
        ele.click()
        time.sleep(10)


rottentomatoes = rottenTomatoes("Shawshank")
rottentomatoes.search()
```

Added the full code the element was inside shadowRoot , so you have to use javascript

Comment: @themm1 updated full answer , it was inside shadow dom .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `requests`:

```
import requests

shearch = "Shawshank"
choose_type = "movie"
url = f"https://www.rottentomatoes.com/napi/search/all?type={choose_type}&searchQuery={shearch}"

r = requests.get(url)
r_json = r.json()
print(r_json)
```